# C#で既存のクリップボードの内容にフォーマットを追加する方法

Tags: c#

お世話になっております。
度々の質問ですみません。
C#ですでに入っているクリップボードの内容に新しくフォーマットを追加しようとしています。
例えば、クリップボードにファイルがコピーされている状態で、そこに文字列等のデータを追加するイメージです。
下記はクリップボードにあるデータを取得して、そこに文字列を追加しようとしています。

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (data == null){
return;
}else{
data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, 内容);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
}
```

しかし、このコードではうまく動かないようで、文字列がコピーされていないどころか、以前にコピーしていた内容も消えてしまっているようです。
ファイルをコピーした状態で、クリップボードに格納されているフォーマットを確認すると、下記のようになっています。

```
FileDrop,FileNameW,FileName,Preferred DropEffect
```

その後、上記のコードで文字列データを追加すると、フォーマット一覧は下記のようになっていますが、実際に文字列を貼り付けようとしたり、ファイルを貼り付けようとすると、貼り付けできません。

```
FileDrop,FileNameW,FileName,Preferred DropEffect
```

上記コードのどこが問題なのか、教えていただけないでしょうか。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ファイル全体のコピペにテキストを追加するというのは疑問ですね。独立した履歴サポートとすれば、Windows10 1809以降に増えたAPIを使うのでは？ [How to acquire clipboard history in Windows 10 (October Update)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55156730/9014308) それ以前は追加とかは無理かも？

Comment: あるいはここに少し関連する情報がありそうです。[Paste Files from Clipboard with Cut or Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57787840/9014308)

Comment: そうは言ってもそれなりの数のソフトが既にあるので、中にはご質問の機能を備えてかつオープンソースのものもあるかもしれないので、探してみてはどうでしょう。[おすすめのクリップボード拡張ツール - k本的に無料ソフト・フリーソフト](https://www.gigafree.net/utility/clip/)

Answer (score 2):

クリップボードは正確にはOLE Clipboardといい、実体は[コピー元が提供する`IDataObject`を貼り付け先が読み取る](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/data-transfer-interfaces)ことで実現されています。
.NET Frameworkでは`IDataObject`（[`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.idataobject?view=netframework-4.8)）そのままでは扱いづらいため、ランタイムがラップした`IDataObject`（[`System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idataobject?view=netframework-4.8)）が使われます。

質問で挙げられたコードもあくまで自プロセス内でラップしたオブジェクトが対象となっています。また、先に触れたようにコピー元と貼り付け先とが`IDataObject`を介したネゴシエーションですから、第三者が介入できませんし、やるべきでもありません。最悪の場合、ウィルス他、侵入行為と判断され得ます。

Comment: やはりそうですか。了解しました。ありがとうございました。